# How does one send a string which is a value from an <input> HTML tag to a NodeJS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I understand I could do that with `<form action=/serverfile.js method='post'>`, but:

(1) How does one do it with Ajax/Fetch API since they need you to send through a file, like a txt file? I'm only trying to send a string.

(2) How would one do it with `<form action=/serverfile.js method='post'>` too, what would need to be set up on the server end to collect the incoming data?

The answers I have seen use expressjs. I don't want to use expressjs. Is it impossible to do this with vanilla NodeJS?

One way I found to do this with vanilla NodeJS is like so:

HTML

```
<form action="/nodedemo_trial" method="post">
<label> Username </label> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" style="width:200px; font-size:1.5rem" id="username"> <br/> <br/>
<label> Password </label> <br/> <br/>
<input type="text" style="width:200px; font-size:1.5rem" id="password"> <br/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log In" style="width:120px; font-size:1.5rem;" > <br/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="width:120px; font-size:1.5rem;" > <br/> <br/>
</form>
```

NodeJS:

```
var http = require('http');
var form = require('fs').readFileSync('homepage.html');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
if (request.method === "GET") {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.end(form);
}


if (request.method === "POST") {
var postData = '';
request.on('data', function (chunk) {
postData += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
console.log('User Posted:\n' + postData);
response.end('You Posted:\n' + postData);
});
}

}).listen(1000);
```

When I do this though, the inputed text doesn't get posted, only "You Posted:". And how would one do that with an HTML page with multiple post requests, if the way to intercept incoming data is `request.method === "POST"`?

Edit: Used querystring. Still doesn't work.

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

var form = require('fs').readFileSync('homepage.html');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    
if (request.method === "GET") {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.end(form);
}


if (request.method === "POST") {
var postData = '';
request.on('data', function (chunk) {
postData += chunk;
}).on('end', function() {
var post = qs.stringify(postData);
console.log('User Posted:\n' + post);
response.end('You Posted:\n' + post);
});
}

}).listen(1000);
```

Not async either:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var qs = require('querystring');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  fs.readFile('homepage.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);


if (req.method == 'POST') {

        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            if (body.length > 1e6)
                req.connection.destroy();
        }).on('end', function () {
            var post = qs.stringify(body);
            console.log(post);
           //res.end(post);
        });
    } 
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8082);
```

Comment: "*How does one do it with Ajax/Fetch API since they need you to send through a file, like a txt file?*" Can you share the source upon which you're basing your claim that AJAX methodologies or the Fetch API support *only* the sending of arbitrary files and not string data? This claim does not align with the publicly-available documentation I have ever reviewed personally. You seem to be fundamentally misunderstanding what these facilities can support in actuality, and I feel it may be helpful to assist you in pointing out where your misunderstanding may be coming from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js) does work.

Apparently, you need to intercept the data with querystring.parse(postData) to convert it into an object. Converting it into a string via either querystring.stringify(postData) or String(postData)/postData.toString doesn't work. Have no
idea why not.

Comment: If another thread on Stack Overflow answers the question, flag/vote to mark the question as a duplicate of that thread so the system can mark it as such and make it extremely obvious to future visitors that the answers they're looking for may reside there.

Comment: Pls format the posts correctly. It just makes everyone especially reviewers’ lives easy. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).